# Any chance to delete programatically corrupt ranged names (with spaces) in Excel (2007/2010)

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

Is there any way to rename or/and delete corrupted ranged names, which include spaces, e.g. "ACVCutoff_4 1" in Excel file with help of powershell? I got stuck on this. Renaming or deleting names fails.

```
$Excel = New-Object -Com Excel.Application
$wbTo = $Excel.workbooks.open($path)
foreach($name in $wbTo.Names)
{
    $name.Name = $tt -replace '\s+', '_' # name is not affected
    $name.delete() # returns an error Exception calling "Delete" with "0" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
}
```

What I have tried:

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516542/deleting-hidden-name-definitions-with-invalid-names-in-excel-2003)

1. Including Name manager add-in does not solve the issue.
2. "Check R1C1 Reference Style" (check the link) - how can it be achieved by writing a code?

Any other suggestions? I would appreciate your help

I am using powershell v2 and Excel 2007/2010.

That's the file with broken names: [XlsWithBrokenNames](http://goo.gl/yBfGE)

SOLUTION BY Chris Neilsen for those who are also stuck on this:

```
#$wbTo - is workbook with corrupt names
$tempFilePath = $path + "temp.xlsm"
$goodFilePath = $path + "cleanFile.xls"
$wbTo.SaveAs($tempFilePath,52) #save as xlsm
$wbTemp = $Excel.workbooks.open($tempFilePath) # open target
# delete names here
$wbTemp.SaveAs($goodFilePath,56) #save as xls
```

Comment: Can you describe how to create some corrupt named ranges? Or upload a sample ssheet with some corrupt named ranges?

Comment: In my experience, if the name is so corrupted that not even the Name Manager add-in can delete it, nothing can and you need to rebuild the workbook. BTW: If you do rebuild the workbook, do so in small steps and save frequently; nothing worse than accidentally bringing over the corruption and having to start from scratch.

Comment: @RachelHettinger not only do frequent saves, but save frequently under a different filename.

Comment: @chrisneilsen here is the file with corrupt names: http://goo.gl/yBfGE.

Comment: @RachelHettinger what i meant is that installing Name Manager add-in didn't help to delete names with powershell, but manually I can remove these names without Name Manager add-in and without any complications. So the issue here is how to to remove such names using powershell. Thanks

Comment: @baton  Good news is that your file isn't that corrupted. Bad news is I don't have any advice for powershell ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All direct manipulation of the corrupt names i have tried has failed!

But, here's a possible alternative:
`SaveAs` your workbook as a `.xlsm`  You should get a dialog complaining about invalid names, with a option to rename and a `Ok to All` button.  Once saved, close and reopen the file, `Save As` an `.xls` and you should be good to go