# deleted names in a Wbk still exist and refer to locations that don't exist, slow Excel

Tags: excel, names, vba

In VBA Help for the RefersTo Property, they give this  example of listing all the Names in a Wkb (fleshed out so you can run it as is)

```
 Sub showNames()'from VBA Help for "RefersTo"
   Dim newSheet As Worksheet
   Set newSheet = Worksheets.Add
   Dim i As Long, nm As Name
   i = 1
   For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
     newSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = nm.Name
     newSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "'" & nm.RefersTo
     i = i + 1
   Next
   newSheet.Columns("A:B").AutoFit
 End Sub
```

When I run that on my current project, it turns up many Names that I thought were long gone.  But here they are still hanging around and referring to places that no longer exist.  I think this is what's slowing up my system and I'd love to get rid of those Names, but they don't show up in the Define Name window so where do I find them?

edit: Meant to mention that the Links item is greyed out for this Wbk.

Comment: This is a long, roundabout (and possibly ugly) solution, but have you tried migrating all your data into a new workbook? If the wkb is corrupt somehow, this would likely fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**- Updated Answer -**

Since you know the names of the invalid ranges but can't see them in the Name Manager, you can try to delete them manually from the VBA Immediate window. The name you gave `GrPix!patternListRange` indicates a worksheet name so you should be able to delete it by typing

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names("GrPix!patternListRange").Delete
```

or

```
Sheets("GrPix").Names("patternListRange").Delete
```

in the Immediate Window

---

**Original Answer**

Have you tried deleting the invalid names via code?  i.e.

```
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
   If InStr(nm.RefersTo, "OldFileName.xls") > 0 Then
      nm.Delete
   End If
Next nm
```

Comment: Boy, I really had high hopes for this solution.  It looks like it should work, but no, it can't find any of the problem names.

Comment: @Roy, But ShowNames is still finding them?

Comment: Yes, there are 4 of them, all legal names, and with their Refers To all basically the same pattern as above in referring back and forth between PC and Mac. The psf stands for Parallels Shared Folder.

Answer (score 6):

`Update`

**option 1**
A [manual method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555127/zh-t) to delete corrupt names using R1C1  (I can recall JKP stating on another forum he had code to do this but he wasn't prepared to provide it for free)

1. Select Tools, Options and click the General tab.
2. Click the check box next to "R1C1 Reference Style", so that you change the current setting.
3. Press OK.
4. Excel will prompt you to change the name of any name (in all open workbooks!) that contains illegal characters.
5. Select Insert, name, define to delete the newly renamed names.
6. Set the R1C1 Reference style back the way you prefer using Tools, Options, General.

**option 2**
Chris Neilsen posted this at [Any chance to delete programatically corrupt ranged names (with spaces) in Excel (2007/2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8705930/641067)

> But, here's a possible alternative: SaveAs your workbook as a .xlsm
>   You should get a dialog complaining about invalid names, with a option
>   to rename and a Ok to All button. Once saved, close and reopen the
>   file, Save As an .xls and you should be good to go

`Initial Post`
Download [Name Manager](http://www.jkp-ads.com/officemarketplacenm-en.asp) which is the stand out addin by Jan Karel Pieterse and Charles Williams for managing names

It will handle Names that

- now error out as the ranges have been deleted (your issue),
- link to other Workbooks,
- are now corrupt

Plus it will convert global names to local sheet names, and vice versa and so on

[image]

Comment: Thanks brettdj, I've use Name Manager for many years and depend on it to keep my code swept clean of old names, but this time it didn't work. I'm starting to think that the wkb might be corrupted, and Name Manager isn't really built to handle that.  Here's sample of the RefersTo for one of bogus names:  ='\\.psf\Shared on MacHD\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Gridder on All Users Documents\[NewGridder142.xls]Landmarks'!$P$2 0 0 \\.psf\Shared on MacHD\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Gridder on All Users Documents\[NewGridder142.xls]

Comment: That's why I was asking about where these names are stored, so I can go and root them out manually, maybe outside of Excel.  If I could find them.

Comment: +1 for the recco on Name Manager.  I totally agree.  Wonderful program, and most people searching on this topic would find it solved their problem.  Just not mine :(

Comment: +1 for Name Manager. @Roy: If possible may I see the file? you may upload it on wikisend.com or skydrive and share the link here if you want.

Comment: @Roy I have made an update to my post. It would be good to see your file as Sid has requested

Comment: Guys, it has other people's code in it and I can't really let it go.  brettdj@ I don't see xlsm as an option in the dropdown menu.  This is Excel 11, should have said earlier.

Comment: @Roy have you tried the R1C1 workaround ? I have had success with this before with corrupt names that had strange symbols

Answer (score 1):

Here are two more solutions that may work for others searching on this topic, but these still don't fix my own particular Workbook.

I'm still looking.

This is from Aaron Blood and shows the R1C1 method mentioned by brettdj:

```
 Sub RemoveDemonLinks()
   Dim wbBook As Workbook
   Dim nName  As Name
   Dim i      As Long

   Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook

   i = 0
   If wbBook.Names.Count > 0 Then
      With Application
        .ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1
        .ReferenceStyle = xlA1
      End With

    For Each nName In wbBook.Name
       If InStr(nName.RefersTo, "#REF!") > 0 Then nName.Delete
       i = i + 1
    Next nName

    If i > 0 Then MsgBox i & " corrupted names was deleted from " & wbBook.Name
    End If
 End Sub
```

This is from MS Help

```
 ' Module to remove all hidden names on active workbook
    Sub Remove_Hidden_Names()

    ' Dimension variables.
     Dim xName As Variant
     Dim Result As Variant
     Dim Vis As Variant

     ' Loop once for each name in the workbook.
     For Each xName In ActiveWorkbook.Names

       'If a name is not visible (it is hidden)...
       If xName.Visible = True Then
           Vis = "Visible"
       Else
           Vis = "Hidden"
       End If

       ' ...ask whether or not to delete the name.
       Result = MsgBox(prompt:="Delete " & Vis & " Name " & _
           Chr(10) & xName.Name & "?" & Chr(10) & _
           "Which refers to: " & Chr(10) & xName.RefersTo, _
           Buttons:=vbYesNo)

       ' If the result is true, then delete the name.
       If Result = vbYes Then xName.Delete

       ' Loop to the next name.
   Next xName
 End Sub
```

Comment: How did the `Remove_Hidden_Names` code not work? Did it never display a message box with the names that need to be deleted? Did the delete process fail? Did it run without error but the names weren't deleted?

Comment: It ran without error and didn't find any hidden names.  I guess my 4 names are just hidden too well.  Here's another example (no. 1 is above) of a name and Refers To that shouldn't exist. Name: GrPix!patternListRange  Refers To:  ='\\.psf\Shared on MacHD\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Gridder on All Users Documents\[NewGridder142.xls]Landmarks'!$Z$2 0 0 \\.psf\Shared on MacHD\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\Gridder on All Users Documents\[NewGridder142.xls]

Comment: and typing `ActiveWorkbook.Names("GrPix!patternListRange").Delete` or `Sheets("GrPix").Names("patternListRange").Delete` in the Immediate Window won't work? It makes no sense. The only diff between the two procedures' For Loop is that one uses a Variant and the other uses a Name object variable. That shouldn't make any difference. I have to second what the others are saying. I don't think I can give any more help without looking at the actual file.

Comment: YES!!! That did it.  I have no idea why the other approaches couldn't find those names, but I used the second of your suggestions, just changed the Name and ran it 4 times, and it cleaned them out FINALLY.  Thanks for hanging in there msichab1, I'd almost given up.  If you can repeat this in the form of an Answer, I'll check it off.